# Why does the Gridview.builder overflow? (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I have been trying to fix this bug without success. I am trying to make a `Gridview.builder` widget that will hold the buttons for a calculator. I want the widget to fit on the lower part of the screen without overflowing. I tried to fix it by wrapping a `Gridview` into a `Contianer` or a `ConstrainedBox` with a certain height and width. However, the Gridview still keeps overflowing.

Here is my code for the Gridview:

```
           Expanded(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: ScreenHeight(context) * .3,
                maxHeight: ScreenHeight(context) * .4,
              ),
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: ScreenHeight(context) * .02,
                    left: ScreenHeight(context) * .02),
                child: GridView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: buttons.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: getCrossAxisCount(context)),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    // Clear Button
                    if (index == 0) {
                      return CalcButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userInput = '';
                            calcAnswer = '';
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.blue[50],
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                      );
                    }

                    // +/- button
                    else if (index == 1) {
                      return CalcButton(
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.blue[50],
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                      );
                    }

                    // % Button
                    else if (index == 2) {
                      return CalcButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userInput += buttons[index];
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.blue[50],
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                      );
                    }

                    // Delete Button
                    else if (index == 3) {
                      return CalcButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userInput = userInput.substring(
                                0, userInput.length - 1);
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.blue[50],
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                      );
                    }

                    // Equal_to Button
                    else if (index == 18) {
                      return CalcButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            equalPressed();
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.orange[700],
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    }

                    //  other buttons
                    else {
                      return CalcButton(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userInput += buttons[index];
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: isOperator(buttons[index])
                            ? Colors.blueAccent
                            : Colors.white,
                        textColor: isOperator(buttons[index])
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.black,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Here is my code for CalcButton:

```
class CalcButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final color;
  final textColor;
  final String buttonText;
  final onTap;

  CalcButton({
    this.color,
    this.textColor,
    this.buttonText = "",
    this.onTap,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(.3),
        child: ClipRRect(
          child: Container(
            color: getCalcButtonColor(calcTheme,
                buttonText), //gets calc button color from created method
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                buttonText,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: getButtonTxtColor(calcTheme,
                      buttonText), //gets button txt color from created method
                  fontSize: ScreenWidth(context) * .05,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how it looks:
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZVjA.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRLL8.png)

Note that the `ScreenHeight()` and `ScreenWidth()` functions are functions that return the value of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`

I have also tried to remove `Expanded()` and only use a `ConstrainedBox`, but the same thing still happens.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the buttons array?

Comment: Here is the buttons array:                                                                                       
`final List<String> buttons = [
  "C",
  "+/-",
  "%",
  "DEL",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "/",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "x",
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "-",
  "0",
  ".",
  "=",
  "+"
];`